# Cannot access OneDrive storage for inter tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I try to create an application, with which the user in another company/tenant could access his/her OneDrive storage. But failed. It's really appreciated that if anyone could tell me what or which steps I had made mistakes.

(I haded searched the posts and seems not the same issues reported here.)

Detail as below:
The user (user01@company.com), who is in Tenant X, wants to use the service/system (which is developed by Tenant Y) to access the files on his/her One Drive storage.

**1.)** Tenant Y had already got the Azure service and had subscribed Office 365 service (as the One Drive API need SPO license).

**2.)** With AAD in the Tenant Y, I added the user's email (use01@company.com) in the active directory (AAD) as a guest user, and the user had received the notification email and accept it.

**3.)** With AAD in the Tenant Y, I registered a new application, selected **Accounts in any organizational directory** option from **Supported account types** section, setup the redirect URI.

**4.)** Added the delegated API privilege for Graph API (such as the *Files.ReadWrite* and *Files.ReadWriteAll*), and approved the new added privileges request.

**5.)** Created a new client secret for the application.

**6.)** With the tenant Id, client Id and client secret of the application, now I could start OAuth2 authentication flow for the user (user01@company.com). And finally, I got the **access token** for this user.

**7.)** With the access token, it's no problem to get the user's profile https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

**8.)** It would complain *401 Unauthorized* error for this request: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive .
(By the way, such request will be no problem for the user in the same Tenant Y)

Response as the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: ffef8bc9-11e7-4d07-9df3-e3cee81ef7b2
client-request-id: ffef8bc9-11e7-4d07-9df3-e3cee81ef7b2
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East Asia","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_19"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2020 07:13:00 GMT
Content-Length: 249
 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "There has been an error authenticating the request.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-24T07:13:01",
      "request-id": "ffef8bc9-11e7-4d07-9df3-e3cee81ef7b2"
    }
  }
}
```

- edited: 07/02 ---------------------------------------

Appended the request to get the access token:

1.) Use this GET request to get the authorization code:
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id-of-TenantY}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client-id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpersonal%2Ftoken&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&prompt=consent&state=13570](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id-of-TenantY%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7Bclient-id%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpersonal%2Ftoken&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&prompt=consent&state=13570)

2.) User01@company.com sign in and approve the auth request, and the local http server would get the auth code.

3.) send POST request to: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id-of-TenantY}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id-of-TenantY%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token), with the request parameters in body to get the access token, as the image in the link. [screenshot of the POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fZ1N.png)

4.) use the result access token to send target Graph API request. And the result would be as this image.[Result of the /me/drive API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvOl5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding use01@company.com as a guest user in Tenant Y is unnecessary. Just make sure that it has SPO license in Tenant X.

And before you call Microsoft Graph API for the user, construct the URL for granting tenant-wide admin consent to it. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent).

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id of Tenant X}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id of the Azure AD app in Tenant Y}
```

Log in with an admin in Tenant X to do the admin consent for **Tenant X**. After that you could access OneDrive storage for the user in Tenant X.

Please note that you should call the `/authorize` and `/token` endpoints for **Tenant X**.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id-of-TenantX}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client-id}&......
```

**AND**

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id-of-TenantX}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks a lot for the comments. However, I had verified and retried per your suggestion, but the same error happened. :-(  I had confirmed that the user01@company.com has SPO license in Tenant X (who has already haven OneDrive and some files created in it), and had done the admin consent for Tenant X (in fact, the user01@company.com is the admin). Had no idea on what I still missed.

Comment: @Crab Please decode your access token in https://jwt.io/ to see what scopes are included.

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks for the hint. I think it should include the required privilege in scope after decoding the access token, the part including the scopes are as the followings: 
`... 
"puid": "10032000C96A8908",
  "scp": "AllSites.Manage AllSites.Read AllSites.Write Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All MyFiles.Read MyFiles.Write openid profile User.Read User.ReadBasic.All email",
  "signin_state": [
    "kmsi"
  ], 
.... 
`

Comment: @Crab Can you share the full request of getting the access token?

Comment: Hi Allen,
For your information, I had edited the post to add the request of getting the access token. (It would be too long when input in the comments directly.)

Comment: @Crab Oh I'm sorry I have made a mistake. You should construct the URL for granting tenant-wide admin consent to it for **Tenant X** rather than Tenant Y. And you also need to call the `/authorize` and `/token` endpoints for **Tenant X**. I'll update my answer right now.

Comment: Hi Allen,
Yeah! You're right, use the tenant-id of Tenant X instead of Tenant Y will solve this problem! Thank you very much!!